# Bibtex category labels in R plot

Tags: r, axis-labels, bibtex

I am creating a dotplot with R. Every entry of the dotplot is the bibtexkey of a study by some authors, and the plotted variable is the p-value of a significance test.

In other words the data frame contains one column with the latex paper citation command, e.g. \cite{Author2005} and one column with the p-value of the test, e.g. 0.043.

What I want to do is to create a dotchart in which the labels are the compiled citations (with the proper style), such that, in the example above, the label is, e.g., Author (2005).

I know that it is possible to include latex in legend and in axis labels etc... but in this case, since bibtex (that needs compiling) is involved, I think I need a device that outputs tex code.

I tried with [TikZdevice](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tikzDevice/index.html) but I have a label width problem: I suspect label width is computed with respect to the bibtexkey and not to the compiled label (that can be considerably longer) and hence I have labels overlapping with the data...

Any further hints?

Thanks!

Comment: You can import bibtex citations via the `bibtex` package and find all the available references. I'm stuck at how to format the author information, though. I can't find an easy way of "weaving" this information the way LaTeX handles it.